# Simple responsive images method

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, desktop, tablet

Im looking for a very simple method for responsive images.

The site im building has huge background images, which I need to keep for desktops.

However, these are too large to work on tablets/mobiles. It seems that if I reduce the images to 50% size, they will work on all screens.

Is there any simple way to have two sets of images in two different folders, and then select the folder based on the browser being used?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use media queries to denote 2 sets of images (and more). For example:

```
#myBg {
    background-image: url('bigVersion.jpg');
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #myBg {
    background-image: url('smallerVersion.jpg');
  }
}
```

Simple example, showing two different images when the window width is above 600px and below. You can do a lot more with it.

Read more about media queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries